# React isn't updating the visual data, but useState has the right value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a weird problem. In my React project I have a useState([]) variable containing information. On the website I have a "add" button that adds a new price-object to the array.

This is then visually shown on the website with map. Each section (object in the array) has a delete-button. When I delete a section it only delete the newly added object. BUT, when I console.log() the updated values, it have deleted right object.

So, to summarize. In the stored values, it deletes correct, but it won't show it right visually. Someone who may be able to help?

---

Here is the code:

My .map() code, with the code for deleting a section at the bottom:

```
{courseData.prices?.map((price, i) => {
  return (
    <div
      className='flex flex-wrap bg-white mb-4 p-2 rounded-md shadow-md'
      key={i}>
      <Input
        label='Navn'
        value={price.name}
        width='1/2'
        white
        isRequired
        handleChange={(e) => updatePrice(e, i, 'name')}
      />
      <Input
        label='Beskrivelse'
        value={price.description}
        width='1/2'
        white
        isRequired
        handleChange={(e) => updatePrice(e, i, 'description')}
      />
      <Input
        label='Pris'
        type='number'
        width='1/2'
        value={price.price}
        white
        isRequired
        handleChange={(e) => updatePrice(e, i, 'price')}
      />
      <Input
        label='Gyldighet (dager)'
        type='number'
        width='1/2'
        value={price.days}
        white
        isRequired
        handleChange={(e) => updatePrice(e, i, 'days')}
      />
      <button
        type='button'
        onClick={() => {
          setCourseData((courseData) => {
            return {
              ...courseData,
              prices: courseData.prices.filter((item) => item !== price),
            }
          })
        }}
        className='flex items-center min-w-max rounded-md px-2 py-1 m-1 bg-white-light shadow-md font-semibold text-gray-500 active:shadow-none'>
        <XIcon className='h-4 w-4' />
        <p className='font-medium ml-1'>Fjern</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

A picture of the visual components before something is deleted:
[image]

A picture of the visual components after number 2 (the middle one) is deleted:
[image]

The stored data after the middle one is deleted (you see that the stored data and the visual components dont have the same names):

[image]

Comment: The issue here i think is related to key . provide a unique key instead of the index for your div rendered inside the map  . `key={price.courseID}`

Comment: Also in the screenshot which you have shared why the objects in index 0 is different to the one in index 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ju6zf2?file=src/App.js), but everything is working as expected.

I'm guessing that there is some bad data causing this issue, but I also agree with what was suggested in the comments: compare attributes of the objects instead of comparing the objects themselves.

Use this:

```
setCourseData(courseData => {
  return {
    ...courseData,
    prices: courseData.prices.filter(item => item.id !== price.id)
  };
```

instead of this:

```
setCourseData(courseData => {
  return {
    ...courseData,
    prices: courseData.prices.filter(item => item !== price)
  };
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, could you share more of the data?